# Visualizing Market Closing Values in Python Using MatPlotLib and YahooFinance

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
#imports
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import date, timedelta
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight') 

#Get Albemarle Information 
ALBINFO = yf.Ticker("ALB")
# Valid options are 1d, 5d, 1mo, 3mo, 6mo, 1y, 2y,
# 5y, 10y and ytd.
print(ALBINFO.history(period="2y"))


#Graph the Close Values

plt.figure(figsize = (12.2,4.5))
plt.plot(ALBINFO['Close'], label = 'Close')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.title('Close Price History')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price USD')
plt.show()
```

I am writing this code on Python Visual Studio Code.
I am trying to be a graphical representation of the ALB closing stock price.
However, whenever I run the code, only a blank screen shows up.

The computer states that there is a problem with the line
`plt.plot(ALBINFO['Close'], label = 'Close')`.
Could someone help understand what is wrong with this line?
Thank you

I coded the lines above and excepted a graph of closing prices but only got a blank graph.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @John H. did you see the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a dataframe(object) in order to use it. In this case, ALBINFO is overwritten:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import date, timedelta
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

#Get Albemarle Information
ALBINFO = yf.Ticker("ALB")
# Valid options are 1d, 5d, 1mo, 3mo, 6mo, 1y, 2y,
# 5y, 10y and ytd.
ALBINFO = ALBINFO.history(period="2y")

#Graph the Close Values

plt.figure(figsize = (12.2,4.5))
plt.plot(ALBINFO['Close'], label = 'Close')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.title('Close Price History')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price USD')
plt.show()
```